# Python: Replace brackets with minus sign in list

Tags: python, list

```
A= ['(100)','(98.2)', '400', '500']
```

How to replace the list that number with brackets with minus sign? I prefer a simple one line code.

The desired output as below:

`A= ['-100','-98.2', '400', '500']`

My way is very lengthily

```
if '(' in A[0]:
      A[0] = -float(A[0].translate(None,"(),"))
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Show me your code, and I'll show you mine. ;-)

Comment: @KaushikNP You can still do better.... Hint: `str.strip`. Also note that the goal is not to add `-` before everything. I didn't downvote your answer, but I can see your first answer got it wrong.

Comment: @KaushikNP Even as a comment, this still outputs a wrong output

Comment: @KaushikNP read the question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**
`str.strip` + a *list comprehension*.

```
>>> ['-' + y.strip('()') if '(' in y else y for y in A]
['-100', '-98.2', '400', '500']
```

---

**Option 2**
Modifying the first method with a `map` + `lambda`.

```
>>> list(map(lambda y: '-' + y.strip('()') if '(' in y else y, A))
['-100', '-98.2', '400', '500']
```

Personally, I prefer the list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use regex, pretty nice-

```
import re
res = [re.sub(r"\((.*)\)", r"-\1", x) for x in orig]
```